# upload_file dont work properly on my server

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

```
function upload_cover(){
    $config_cover['upload_path'] = 'img/blog/';
    $config_cover['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|tif';
    get_instance()->load->library('upload', $config_cover);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('myFile') )
    {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $path = 'img/blog/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
        return $path;
    }
}
function upload_file(){
    $config_file['upload_path'] = 'document/blog/';
    $config_file['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|txt|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx';
    $this->upload->initialize($config_file);
    if ($_FILES['myDoc']) {
        if($this->upload->do_upload('myDoc'))
        {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $path = 'document/blog/'.$upload_data['file_name'];
            return $path;
        }
    }
}
```

these code are work properly on my computer but when i deploy it on my server it's work only "upload_cover" but upload_file is not working i have no idea....

Comment: Please do not post duplicates of your question. React to the feedback and follow-up questions in the other one instead.

Answer (score 0):

First $_FILES return an array(), please try to edit the keys with this code to know exactly that you receive ;

```
foreach($_FILES as $kt => $val)
{
echo "Key = $kt and val = $val<br>",PHP_EOL;
}
```

and comme back with the response, or maybe the result give you the answer;

I stay 20 minutes before leaving.

Hava nice day;